# how to resolve jar resource in eclipse html editor

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, maven, webjars

First, my application loads and runs in a web container.  The question is specific to the eclipse html editor.

I happen to use maven and webjars.org to obtain the angularjs for my application, and import the maven project into eclipse.

As per webjars.org documentation, my html file has

`<script src="webjars/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>`

Eclipse html editor shows an error on that line: "Undefined script file: (webjars/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js)"

How can this error get resolved?
`

Comment: Do you have m2e and m2e-wtp installed, and is it recognized by Eclipse as a project that's built by Maven?

Comment: m2e: yes, version 1.5.0.20140606-0033, m2e-wtp: yes, version 1.1.0.20140611-1646; finally, yes, project recognized as 'maven'.  All this I think can be inferred by one of my opening statements: "my application loads and runs in a web container'.  I see that I was not specific enough.  The application, built within eclipse, can load and run in a web container.  Thanks.

Comment: Where *is* angular.js? And what Type is that message in the Problems View? I'm skeptical it's the editor itself or its validator saying that.

Comment: angular.js is a resource in a project jar.  See http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3.  Type is 'Web Resource Problem"

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources instead of the editor. Not sure how to actually solve it, though.

Comment: The webjars documentation says this:  "This works because anything in a META-INF/resources directory in a JAR in WEB-INF/lib is automatically exposed as a static resource."  So, I think the validation of an html is unaware of this rule, or eclipse needs to be configured as such.  The rule  works fine in a servlet3 container, just not in eclipse html validator.

Comment: If you use https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources your error is normal because Eclipse WTP / Web Resouirces doesn't support WebJars. Please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/issues by attaching a simple project with webjars (I have never used this feature).